# Synchronization between javafx and standard thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How can Itell JavaFX to wait until my process is finished without blocking?

```
public LoadResult load(URL url) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        Platform.runLater(() ->{
            done = false;
            engine.load("");
        });
        attesa();
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        Platform.runLater(() ->{
            done = false;
            engine.load(url.toString());
        });
        attesa();
    }).start();
    return new LoadResult(url, parsed, ex);
}

private void attesa(){
        while (!done){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

I want that this method returns when the variable "done" is true, that means my pocess is finished.
With my code, the javafx doesn't block but the method returns when the process is not finished, so the variable "parsed" is null. how can i solve?

Comment: have you tried `join()`

Comment: i didn't try `join()`, can you tell me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `attesa();` call outside the run method of threads, juste before returning the LoadResult

The problem is you are waiting into the other threads instead of waiting into the current thread before returning the result

EDIT :
You can also use CompletableFuture as follow :

```
        CompletableFuture<LoadResult> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ( ) -> {
            LoadResult result = null; // load and build LoadResult 
            return result;
        } );

        future.thenAccept( result -> { /* do some stuff with result here */ }  );
```

Comment: if i do this, i block the javafx thread and i can't do anything else

Comment: So, consider the use of class ExecutorService. Submit a runnable to it, get a future and add a listener to it to get result when done. Platform.runLater() is for executing code into the UI Thread of JavaFX, not to do some complex stuff in parallel

Comment: i use the `ExecutorService` in another class when i have to load a lot of pages, this method have to load 1 page and he cannot return until the page is completly loaded

    `res = exec.submit(() -> {

            while (loaderPool.isEmpty()) {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }

            Loader loader=loaderPool.poll();
            LoadResult r=loader.load(url);
            loaderPool.add(loader);

            return r;

        });
        tasks.add(res);
        return tasks.poll();
    }` 
(sorry it's my first time i use stack overflow xD )

Comment: @Daniele If you call it into Javafx thread, and it cannot return until load is complete, you must block the current thread (the javafx thread)... Otherwise, consider using parallel threads by using : ExecutorService or CompletableFurure to execute the code in parallel thread and trigger action when done (see example in edited comment)

Comment: i'm sorry i'm trying but it doesn't work... this method is called in another class, not in the javafx class, so what i know is that i need the `Platform.RunLater()` and i need another thread to wait until my page is loaded but my problem is that the variable "parsed" is null because when the thread with `attesa()` starts, the method returns `null` because the page is still not loaded. I've just started with java threads so i don't have a lot of knowledge about it sorry.

Comment: There is no javafx class, but a javafx thread. Many classes can have code executed on this thread. When you call your load() method, you ask to load "later" in javafx thread, and return immediately a LoadResult which contains parsed field which is obviously null (because you ask for loading later in parallel). Two options, as already said : Block the current thread and wait the end of the result, or rewrite your code to use a parallel code pattern considering the result is not present right now but adding a trigger when it will be available

Comment: I already tried the first solution, when i block the current thread it blocks everything and it doesn't load anything, so i think the solution is to rewrite the code, but i don't know what to use to rewirte the code

Comment: @Daniele Oh yes, it's blocking because you are already in javafx ui thread, and ask for loading in this tread later. You can create a new thread instead of Platform.runlater() call and be sure that done field is set to true when load is finished. But the correct approch is to rewrite the code using Completable future like in my example. Start the load into the runAsync() method to do the load in a new parrallel thread. When the load is finished, the result will be available into the method thenApply(). Here load is finished, trigger some action to continue

Comment: i just have to return the result when it is ready:
(i don't know how to put the code in a separate window but i paste it the same here: 

public LoadResult load(URL url) {

        CompletableFuture<LoadResult> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ( ) -> {
            LoadResult result = null;
            done = false;
            engine.load(url.toString());
            attesa();
            result = new LoadResult(url,parsed, ex);
            return result;
        } );

        future.thenAccept( result -> {});
        return null; // return what? i can't return future.get()

    }

Comment: returns the future, and in your calling parent, add a thenAccept() call on it to trigger what you want to do with the loadresult